# wait till an upload is completed and then continue the script

Tags: javascript

How can I wait in an for Loop till an upload is completed and then continue the for Loop with the next number?

I have searched the Internet but there is only the setTimeout function and so on!
Here My code:

```
for(var f=0;f<4;f++){
   var formdata = new FormData();
   var id = f+1;
   var file = _("filestyle-"+id).files[0];
   formdata.append("file"+id, file);
   var title = _("title"+id).value;
   formdata.append("title"+id, title);
   document.getElementById("uploadname").innerHTML=title+"is uploading<br>";
   var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
   ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
   ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
   ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
   ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
   ajax.open("POST", "../swupload.php");
   ajax.send(formdata);
}
```

in the completeHandler a variable is set to 1

Comment: Can you share your current code that you have?

Comment: You need call back after file upload. this may help you

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722601/how-do-i-call-a-js-callback-when-a-file-upload-completes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set code you want to execute at different stages of ajax request as:-

readyState  Holds the status of the XMLHttpRequest. Changes from 0 to 4:

0: request not initialized 
1: server connection established 
2: request received  
3: processing request  
4: request finished and response is ready

However in your case you want to execute code after completion of upload, it may be achieve like that:

```
ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
{
     if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200)
     {
          // code to execute after upload
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is asynchronous, so you can't expect your other synchronous code to wait for it. What you can do is replace your loop with a function, and recall it from your `completeHandler` callback.

```
post(1);

function post(id) {
   var formdata = new FormData();
   var file = _("filestyle-"+id).files[0];
   formdata.append("file"+id, file);
   var title = _("title"+id).value;
   formdata.append("title"+id, title);
   document.getElementById("uploadname").innerHTML=title+"is uploading<br>";
   var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
   ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
   ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
   ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
   ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
   ajax.open("POST", "../swupload.php");
   ajax.send(formdata);

   function completeHandler() {
     if (id < 5) post(id + 1);
   }
}
```

If `completeHandler` must be defined outside of this function, you can preserve the id with a closure:

```
ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler(id), false);
```

```
function completeHandler(id) {
  return function() {
    if (id < 5) post(id + 1);
  }
}
```